# Dismissing modally presented ViewController always throws me back to root

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I've had this issue for months with multiple views, both Apple provided like ImagePicker and VCs from storyboard.

I believe that it has something to do with the underlying views we have both a tab bar controller and navigation controller in most views.

Strange thing is using some open source views from pods does not cause this bug.

So I'm two views deep on a navigation controller and present another view modally on top with `present(vc, animated: true, completion: {})`

Works like a charm, now dismissing that view with `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` throws me back all the way to the initial view or root view of the navigation controller, had both happen before, depending on the presented view.

**Update**:
Build a sample project trying to reproduce the behavior but failed. Drew a reduced diagram to better explain the current bug behavior. 
Also noticed that if I'm invoking the post view one step earlier in the Fandom view it works as expected.

[image: sketch]

Comment: Calling `dismiss` will dismiss the view controller you called it from. There's not enough here, though, to diagnose your problem. I'd suggest you create a [minimal, yet complete, verifiable example of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (a MCVE). Start with a blank project and figure out what you need to add to reproduce your problem. But until you show us what we need to do to reproduce your problem, we can't help.

Comment: Created simple sample project and obviously it works as expected there. I'm trying to debug the entry point right now, it's a rather large project which multiple people have worked on, so I'm not quite sure where, when or what broke it. Will update when I find more info

Comment: The other approach is to take a copy of your current project and start ripping out unrelated stuff, repeating testing it as you're going along to see if the problem still manifests itself. In that process, you'll likely identify what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i am using UITabBarController, and I wrote code in viewWillAppear of UITabBarController

```
self.selectedIndex = 2
```

so when i present any thing from any controller whose parent is UITabBarController and when i dismiss that it automatically open third tab of UITabBarController.

Maybe you explicitly wrote any code to select specific index of TabBar.

Maybe this is useful for you or anyone else.